# Google+ badge on websites

Tags: google-plus, google-sites, badge

I am trying to put a Google+ badge on my recently created websites at [sites.google.com](http://sites.google.com). When I copy the code and paste it into the HTML box actually nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are trying to paste the code shown here https://developers.google.com/+/web/badge/ actually you should get an error when trying to paste it into the HTML editor, as the **script** tag is not allowed (http://support.google.com/sites/answer/90540?hl=en). To insert a *+1 button* you can click on *Insert > +1 Button*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use to insert a Google+ Badge into your Google Sites pages using a custom gadget:

1. Get your Google+ profile ID, which you can get from the URL of your profile. The ID would be `123456789012345678901` for this URL: `https://plus.google.com/123456789012345678901/` or would be `+LarryPage` for this URL: `https://plus.google.com/+LarryPage/`
2. Edit the page that you want to add the badge
3. Choose **Insert**-> **...More gadgets...**
4. Search for G+ Badge.
5. Paste your profile ID into the G+ ID field.
6. Configure additional options as necessary for your page. You might need to adjust dimensions of the gadget container to get the badge to work well in your site.

Gadgets have limitations, this might not work perfectly but its probably the best way to get a badge onto your page.

Comment: Is there a similar menu option for the Badge?

Comment: Updated my answer to specifically show how to insert a badge using a custom gadget.

Comment: The URL on step 5 returns Error 404 (Not found)!!1

Comment: It appears that has moved or is gone now. There is a badge available in the "more widgets" section titled "G+ badge" that you can configure.

Answer (score 0):

There is a configuration tool for the Google+ Badge that you can find at https://developers.google.com/+/web/badge/.

The key points are that you need to add the HTML as a widget and include the JavaScript tag--which is the same JavaScript that loads any of our Google+ attributes.

I also made a 3 minute video explaining these steps last year, which you can view at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLG4IIIPgnc.

Comment: This doesn't work with Google Sites - the HTML gets stripped out.